# How to enable disable anchor tag received as html in java string

Tags: javascript, java, extjs

Here is the brief explanation of what i am trying to do

1. I have initialized html anchor tag like this <a ... /> and saved in Java string variable
2. I have passed that strings into javascript where i am using Ext.js
3. I have successfully shown the html in Ext.js Grid columns
4. Now unable to perform step 5
5. Need to disable and enable anchor tags for some values

The intended logic to handle enable and disable anchor tags are below with pseudocode

```
if(status === "Pending")
     uploadActionBtn = enable
     downloadActionBtn = disable
   else if (status === "Under Observation")
     uploadActionBtn = disable
     downloadActionBtn = enable
```

My **Java code**

```
downloadActionBtn = "<a href='downloadDocument.do?cmStudDocId="+ cmStudDocId + "'><i class='fa fa-download fa-lg'></i></a>";
uploadActionBtn = "<a href='#' target='_blank' onclick=\"return openDocumentDiv(uploadFormDiv,'"+cmStudDocId+"');return false;\"  style='padding:1px 7px;'><i class='fa fa-upload fa-lg'></i></a>";
```

My **Ext.js code**

```
var downloadActBtn = records.documents[i].downloadActionBtn;
var uploadActBtn = records.documents[i].uploadActionBtn;
var actionsBtns = uploadActBtn  + downloadActBtn; 

columns:[
{
    text: 'Action',
    sortable: false,
    dataIndex: 'actionBtns',
    lockable:true,
    width:75
}

]
```

Comment: Do you need to enable/disabled links in standard grid column or do you need to enable/disable action buttons in grid action column?

Comment: In my case links are action buttons, so actually i need to show action buttons in grid column. I know anchor tag can not be disable, we can disable but with css help. I have used buttons instead of anchor before but same issue with buttons i am passing html as string in ext.js how can i modify it

Comment: Your column is standard grid text column, it is not action column. May you send only urls and implement native action column? WHAT IS IMPORTANT, which version of ExtJs and TOOLKIT are you using?

Comment: Just for information, it is very bad idea to get from BackEnd html fragments to render them in FrontEnd. It is better to send only values, strings (URLs), ints..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample for enabling/disabling links in grid with renderer of text field and action column

[image]

```
var urlStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['url'],
    data: [{
        url: "www.google.de",
        linkEnabled: true
    }, {
        url: "www.bing.de",
        linkEnabled: false
    }, {
        url: "www.stern.de",
        linkEnabled: true
    }, {
        url: "www.focus.de",
        linkEnabled: false
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: "Urls Grid",
    store: urlStore,
    columns: [{
        text: 'URL',
        dataIndex: 'url',
        flex: 1,
        renderer: function(value, metaData, record){
            var cellContent = value;
            if(record.get('linkEnabled')) {
                cellContent = '<a href="' + value + '">' + value + '</a>';
            }
            return cellContent;
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'actioncolumn',
        text: "Action",
        items: [{
            glyph: 'xf08e@FontAwesome',
            tooltip: 'Edit',
            handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                var record = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                if(record.get('linkEnabled')) {
                    alert("window.location = " + record.get('url'));
                }
            }
        }]
    }],
    margin: 5,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```